# How to fix it? - variable contains something else than should be

Tags: php

Yesterday I finished construction of class in which I use `__call` method (described few days ago). But it runs correctly until I use `__call` method.

Its all code is

```
public function __call($Function, array $Parameters)
{
    if(method_exists($this, $Function))
    {
        call_user_func_array(array($this, $Name), $Parameters);
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            if(!preg_match('/[A-Za-z]_Style|Attribute/i', $Function))
            {
                throw new MarC_Exception(...);
            }
        }
        catch(MarC_Exception $Exception)
        {
            $Exception -> ExceptionWarning(...);
        }

        $Function = explode('_', $Function);
        $Function[0] = strtolower($Function[0]);

        ...

        $Options = array('Style', 'Attribute');

        if($Function[1] == $Options[0])
        {
            if(strtolower($Function[0]) == $this -> Elements['top'])
            {
                array_unshift($Parameters, $Function[0]);
                call_user_func_array(array($this, 'Set_AllElementStyles'), $Parameters);
            }
            else
            {
                if($this -> Check_StyleName($Parameters[0]))
                {
                    array_unshift($Parameters, $Function[0]);
                    call_user_func_array(array($this, 'Set_AllElementStyles'), $Parameters);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(strtolower($Function[0]) == $this -> Elements['top'])
            {
                array_unshift($Parameters, $Function[0]);
                call_user_func_array(array($this, 'Set_AllElementAttributes'), $Parameters);
            }
            else
            {
                if($this -> Check_AttributeName($Parameters[0]))
                {
                    array_unshift($Parameters, $Function[0]);
                    call_user_func_array(array($this, 'Set_AllElementAttributes'), $Parameters);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but problem is (at this time) in `preg_match` usage. There he sees (I don't know why) that content of variable function is Set_AllElementStyles (that I call below in call_user_func_array) instead (for example) Body_Style.

If place into code `echo $Function` to see what really happens, it calls

- `Body_style` if it is in the beginning of function code or inside if-branch of if-else
- `Body_Style` and `Set_AllElementStyles` if it is inside else-branch of if-else

**Where did I make error that causes this problem?** (How to fix it?)

**Edit 1:**
Example of object of class RootAssembler_Html (that is final coverage of abstract class UniqueAssembler), together with usage of `__call`.

```
$VMaX = new MarC\RootAssembler_Html();
$VMaX -> Set_ExportWay();
$VMaX -> Set_Content();
$VMaX -> Set_Content($Text);
$VMaX -> Body_Style('background-color', '#ABCDEF');
$VMaX -> Body_Attribute('id', 'test');
$VMaX -> Execute();
```

Output:

```
<html>
    <head>
    /* some text that is not set in the first usage of method Set_Content */
    </head>
    <body id='test' style="background-color: #ABCDEF;">
    /* some text that was set in the second usage of method Set_Content */
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i think you should provide some shorter piece of working code so we could see more easily what is the problem - and also you would show us that you tried some debugging... Btw. are you aware that your regex /[a-z]\_Style|Attribute/i matches: either the word "Attribute" or a letter followed by '_' and "Style"?

Comment: @JanLegner: Problem is not in regex, itself (even if it may wrong). Problem is that `Set_AllElementStyles` should not appear there.

Comment: @Václav What about an example calling `__call` with params, along with the real output and the desired output?

Comment: @Václav Pretty sure you are missing variable `$Name` in `call_user_func_array(array($this, $Name), $Parameters);`. I'm pretty sure this variable is undefined. You either pass it as a param or declare it as `global` in every other cases it will always be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your problem is with this line:

`call_user_func_array(array($this, $Name), $Parameters)`

Try changing it to:

`call_user_func_array(array($this, $Function), $Parameters)`

and should work.

Because I cannot see where `$Name` variable is defined. It should be pass as a parameter to the function or be a global one. But in both cases I cannot see what is the point to pass it there.

Further I would suggest you changing your regular expression with the following one and fetching the type ot html element you want to set attribute or style to:

`preg_match('/([A-Za-z]+)_(Style|Attribute)/i', $Function, $matches)`

Here an example input:

```
preg_match('/([A-Za-z]+)_(Style|Attribute)/i', "Body_Style", $matches1);
preg_match('/([A-Za-z]+)_(Style|Attribute)/i', "Div_Style", $matches2);
preg_match('/([A-Za-z]+)_(Style|Attribute)/i', "Div_Attribute", $matches3);
```

and output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Body_Style
    [1] => Body
    [2] => Style
)
Array
(
    [0] => Div_Style
    [1] => Div
    [2] => Style
)
Array
(
    [0] => Div_Attribute
    [1] => Div
    [2] => Attribute
)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Usage of `$Name` instead `$Function` in code above - I know that there should be `$Function`. And in my code it was correct. Finally, problem disappeared after I changed usage of call_user_func_array into classic calling of those functions (aside of Set_AllElementsStyles I have there, of course, also Set_AllElementsAttributes). Ouch, currently I found next bug I had there.